# Plugin Context Processors in django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm trying to get django cms' plugin context processors for my hooked app. I followed the documentation http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#plugin-context-processors , but for some reason it doesn't work. Here is a my sample context processor:

```
def test_context_processor(instance, placeholder):
    print instance
    return {'testkey':'testvalue'}
```

and my template:

```
{% load cms_tags %}

<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    {% plugins_media %}
</head>

<body>

{% placeholder "main" %}

</body>
</html>
```

I added a text plugin in the main placeholder, and added the text {{testkey}}. It renders it as {{testkey}} instead of testvalue. The print statement in the context processor gets logged properly - meaning that the context processor is called for sure. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here.

--- Edit ---

My settings file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

gettext = lambda s: s

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

LANGUAGES = [('en', 'en')]
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 0

#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'mycms.db'),
#    }
#}

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'postgresql_psycopg2'           # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME = '***'     # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = '***'             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = '***'         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = '5432'             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '0r6%7gip5tmez*vygfv+u14h@4lbt^8e2^26o#5_f_#b7%cm)u'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.media.PlaceholderMediaMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
)

CMS_PLUGIN_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'helpdocs.cms_context_processors.test_context_processor',
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('example.html', 'Example Template'),
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'mptt',
    'appmedia',
    'south',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'helpdocs',
)
```

Comment: can you paste your settings.py here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Plugin Context Processors are used to process the **context** with which the **templates** of the plugin are rendered. They do not alter the content of any database field (in your case, 'body' on the Text model).

Therefore it will not replace anything in your text plugin. To do what you're trying to do, have a look at Plugin Processors (http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#plugin-processors) which allow you to process the rendered output of a plugin.

To achieve what you're trying to do you would do something like this:

```
def my_plugin_processor(instance, placeholder, rendered_content, original_context):
    return rendered_content.replace('{{ testkey }}', 'testvalue')
```